# Problem with google assistant and app actions in Android TV

Tags: android, actions-on-google, android-tv, app-actions, google-assistant

I use custom intents from the app actions, after executing the command the assistant does not close, it remain open with a twisting throbber, but the focus remains on our application and to close the assistant i need to press the home button.

actions.xml:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<actions>
    <action
        intentName="custom.actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE"
        queryPatterns="@array/feature_queries">
        <parameter
            name="action"
            type="https://schema.org/Text" />
        <parameter
            name="text"
            type="https://schema.org/Text" />

        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://safarov.page.link/open{?item_action,item_text}">
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="action"
                urlParameter="item_action" />
            <parameter-mapping
                intentParameter="text"
                urlParameter="item_text" />
        </fulfillment>
    </action>
</actions>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter
    android:autoVerify="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:host="safarov.page.link"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Intents work out correctly, but the assistant does not close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Actions are currently not supported in Android TV. Stay tuned for updates.

Comment: Any update for Android TV? The codelabs App Actions examples aren't working for ATV. When I run the test tool, I see an error that says, "You don't have an app that can do this". I'm running Android-R. I've tried both the actions.xml & shortcuts.xml examples

Comment: I don't understand why this is not available in Android TV. It would be so useful... Any plans in the road map for enabling this in Android TV?